# Fast CGI in Apache: Couldn't bind unix domain socket

Tags: apache, sockets, config, fastcgi, httpd.conf

After ruling out the trivial causes like missing permission to write to the file I'm looking for the cause of this. The file `fcgid.conf` provides only basic settings and I couldn't verify what port is it trying to open. How can I grant the permission?

Hint: Maybe the port is blocked by my system, but I didn't find any mention of the port no. in fcgid config.

This is the Apache error log. when a Fast CGI script is loaded:

```
[Tue Oct 06 14:16:24.235309 2015] [fcgid:error] [pid 23141:tid 139803208390720] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: couldn't bind unix domain socket /var/run/httpd/mod_fcgid/23141.256
[Tue Oct 06 14:16:24.235351 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 23141:tid 139803208390720] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/html/azure/testfcgi.fcgi error
[Tue Oct 06 14:16:25.236606 2015] [fcgid:error] [pid 23141:tid 139803208390720] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: couldn't bind unix domain socket /var/run/httpd/mod_fcgid/23141.257
[Tue Oct 06 14:16:25.236682 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 23141:tid 139803208390720] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/html/azure/testfcgi.fcgi error
[Tue Oct 06 14:16:26.237965 2015] [fcgid:error] [pid 23141:tid 139803208390720] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: couldn't bind unix domain socket /var/run/httpd/mod_fcgid/23141.258
[Tue Oct 06 14:16:26.238043 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 23141:tid 139803208390720] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/html/azure/testfcgi.fcgi error
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Apache, but I am familiar with Unix sockets. There is no port number for them. Instead, the file name identifies what to bind to. What are the permissions on /var/run/httpd/mod_fcgid/23141.258? Does it exist? Is /var/run/httpd/mod_fcgid/ write-enabled for the Apache user?

Comment: Access rules are correct for the directory and its subdirectories for user `apache` and group `www`: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache www 8 Oct  6 15:04 fcgid_shm`. What is strange is that the permissions are reset to `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8 Oct  6 15:44 fcgid_shm ` each time I restart the Apache server. I have no idea what is going on there...

Comment: I am talking about this particular location /var/run/httpd/mod_fcgid/ Did you look at it?

Comment: I looked into the location and fixed the permissions recursively for `/var/run/httpd/` and all its subfolders. What I did differently is that I stopped the server. It works now!

Comment: I care for my reputation. Would you mind accepting my answer? :)

Comment: Yep you have it there! :)

Comment: Thank you, sorry for begging :D

Comment: Np if that's all i have to to to get your attention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the problem, fix permissions on the file and path reported by the server.

Comment: It seems necessary to also stop the server